# Method call before statement

Tags: ios, swift

when my buttontouchfinished method call so the statement in this method  is called after the call alphabetic order method what can I do to call statement before the method call. I am a new in IOS.....

```
@objc func btnTouchFinished(sender: UIButton, withevent: UIEvent)  {


    if i == 1 && sender.frame.intersects(button3.frame) {
        if sender.frame == movingChar.frame {

       sender.frame = button3.frame
        button3.setTitle("3", for: .normal)
        movingChar.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)

        movingChar2.isHidden = true
        movingChar3.isHidden = true
        let audio = self.ap.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: "Good Job", type: "mp3")
        audio?.play()
        sleep(2)

        alphabeticOrder(numbers: [1,2,3,4,5])



        } else {
            let audio = self.ap.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: "wrong_drop", type: "mp3")
            audio?.play()
            sender.frame = btnframe

        }
```

and the method alphabetic order is -

```
func alphabeticOrder(numbers: [Int])  {

    for var z in 0...numbers.count - 1 {

    let audio = self.ap.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: "\(numbers[z])", type: "mp3")
            audio?.play()
            sleep(2)
          //  self.nextQuiz.isHidden = false

    }



}
```

Comment: the title of the button3 is change after call the alphabetic order method

Comment: @shubham-kaushik : Can u please elaborate your problem, its really hard to understand what are trying to achieve

Comment: in this image you can see when I move a object 3 to question mark then this method btntouchfinished() call and the question mark is change to number 3 and then the method alphabetic order() method will be call in this method the voice over play and call  from 1 to 5 number ................So the my problem is when the button touch touchfinished method well be call so first voice over from 1 to 5 play and then change the button label changed

Comment: see this image.   https://imageshack.com/a/img922/48/lEGH3E.png